# gi.repository.Notify.Notification.new().add_action() click return

Tags: python, notifications

How I'm I supposed to enter a function when the button has been pressed or that the notification dissapeared?

For now, the code just hangs after making appear the notification, whatever has been done

I tried to gi.repository.Notify.Notification.new().add_action() with a function to execute